# Is it possible to execute a Data Factory Pipeline as a step in a SQL Agent Job on Azure Managed Instance?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-data-factory

I've currently got an ETL process that dynamically builds and executes sql jobs based on job steps that are saved in my database. Included in these jobs are steps to call SSIS packages that move data from one server to another and/or call stored procs on target servers to do further processing. I'm looking at what it would take to migrate our process from SQL Server to a Azure Managed Instance. One of the specific things I'm looking at is the feasibility of replacing the steps that call the SSIS packages with steps that execute Azure Data Factory pipelines or other ADF actions that accomplish the same results. So far I have not run across any examples of this. Anyone have any experience with accessing Data Factory functionality with SQL Agent jobs?

Comment: You can always continue to use SSIS packages in the ADF SSIS runtime, schedule them with Agent and even execute them with the SSIS catalog stored procedures or through ADF Pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

You can run powershell scripts via SQL agent as mentioned in below MSFT docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/run-windows-powershell-steps-in-sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver16

And via powershell and ADF REST APIS, you can trigger the ADF pipelines